# sftp - timestamp | ls -l vs ls -l <file>

Tags: ls, sftp, timestamps

we have the following phenomenon

sftp connectionn and then

```
sftp> ls -l

rw-r--r--    1 530     530           36 Feb 11 08:21 test.txt


sftp> ls -l test.txt

-rw-r--r--    0 530     530           36 Feb 11 09:21 test.txt
```

Does someone have an explanation for the different time stamps?

thx
Antje

Comment: Interesting... if you're using the OpenSSH implementation, then it appears to have two different `ls` routines depending on whether a path argument is given (`do_ls_dir` and `do_globbed_ls`). I wonder if there's a difference in locale handling between the two?

Comment: Could you please double check your transcript? There seems to be a chraracter missing from the permission string.  If this missing character is a `d` character, then the `text.txt` name in the first half of the output is a directory, containing a file that is listed with the second command.  That is, you have `./test.txt/test.txt`.

Comment: Are you working from two different accounts ([Anjtje](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/456169/antje) and [user456231](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/456231/user456231))? If so, please check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) on how to merge these.

Comment: I rolled back the most recent edit from user456231 as only the original user could possibly know what the correct transcript should look like.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different timestamps in SFTP "ls -l" vs. "ls -lh"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/677581/different-timestamps-in-sftp-ls-l-vs-ls-lh)