# Different timestamps in SFTP "ls -l" vs. "ls -lh"

Tags: sftp, timestamps, timezone

I have a 3rd-party SFTP server on which I want to check some file timestamps.

However, I do get different results for the same file if I use `ls -l` vs. `ls -lh`:

```
sftp> ls -l
[...]
-rwxrwxrwx 1 0        0               1963 Nov 15 08:49 foo.txt
[...]

sftp> ls -lh
[...]
-rwxrwxrwx    0 0        0            1.9K Nov 15 07:49 foo.txt
[...]

sftp> ls -l foo.txt
-rwxrwxrwx    0 0        0            1963 Nov 15 07:49 foo.txt

sftp> ls -lh foo.txt
-rwxrwxrwx    0 0        0            1.9K Nov 15 07:49 foo.txt
```

As you can see, the timestamp in `ls -l` is `08:49` whereas the other commands have `07:49`. The server is in Germany which currently is 1h later than UTC, so my guess is that `07:49` is UTC whereas `08:49` is Berlin time.

However, my machine is on UTC:

```
$ cat /etc/timezone 
Etc/UTC
```

My understanding is that, according to the SFTP standard, all timestamps should be in UTC. However I'm not sure whether that understanding is correct (given that there are so many different versions of the standard). I also don't know whether the `sftp` tool somehow postprocesses the timestamps (`man sftp` doesn't mention timezones or timestamps at all).

What could be the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When listing a directory using SFTP protocol, the server provides both structured metadata of files (name, timestamp, size, etc) and textual listing of files.

The OpenSSH `sftp` with `-l` switch prints the textual representation (as formatted by the server). In this case the times are printed according to the server's timezone (at least with the OpenSSH server).

But with `-h` switch, the client has to format the listing from the structured metadata on its own (due to the forced custom formatting of the size), including the timestamp. That's where the difference comes from. The OpenSSH `sftp` client formats the timestamps according to its timezone.

---

When "listing" specific files, the OpenSSH `sftp` probably uses the SFTP "stat" request (not a directory listing, as in the SFTP protocol, the directory listing request does not support filtering to a specific file or a mask). The response to the SFTP "stat" request contains only the structured metadata, not the textual listing. So in this case, the client always have to format the listing locally. So that's why the timestamp matches the timestamp of `-h`.

---

Regarding the [BugZilla entry you have found](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3021): I understand that from user perspective you might see it as a bug. But there's not much the OpenSSH `sftp` client can do about it, if it wants to offer formatting capabilities like `-h`. All it could do is to always format the listing locally to maintain consistency (that's what my WinSCP's `ls` command does for example). But then it would give up on displaying potentially useful (platform specific/proprietary) information contained in the server-side listing.

Comment: To me that sounds like a bug and indeed there is already a ticket for it: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3021

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: The very least that I would expect is that something like this is mentioned in the man page. Personally, I would expect the "standard" commands to behave intuitively, especially I wouldn't expect `ls -l FILENAME` and `ls- l` to behave differently. One could always offer non-standard, server-dependent behavior using a flag or a separate command. But I guess that discussion it better suited for the ticket I've linked to.